# Which versions of crystal reports create rpt files that I can run with an app built with visual studio 2005?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports

I have an app built using Visual Studio 2005, which can run rpt files. The .rpt files are stored in a particular folder and the db has metadata about the report name, filename, and stored procedure to run for it. When a user runs a report I call the appropriate stored proc to get a DataTable, create a `ReportDocument` and load the rpt file, SetDataSource() with the DataTable, then display the report in a `CrystalReportViewer` control.

If my client wants to be able to modify or create their own rpt files, which versions of Crystal Reports do they need to use?

Cross-posted [here](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9699158) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/4572cb81-1d1b-4cac-a29e-be27422c0bcc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://msdn.itags.org/visual-studio/115695/ , CR 11 Release 2 works.  I would thoroughly check this on my end before telling the client, though.

Comment: Don't take my marking this as the answer to indicate I thouroughly tested it :)